# Get absolute path to media folder from django views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to provide an absolute path to a file in my media so that once a file has been uploaded,I can get it through absolute path to it in the media folder..
In my settings.py i have defined the MEDIA_ROOT as;

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
```

and SITE_ROOT as

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

In my models i have a file field that defines where files should be uploaded to as

```
file=models.FileField(upload_to='csvs',blank=True, null=True)
```

In my views, am trying to get the absolute file as

```
if request.method=='POST':
        form=UploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            files=request.FILES['file']
            evidence=request.POST['evidence']
            path_to_tzjmplist_file=default_storage.path(files)
            form.save()
```

this returns the absolute path as

```
"C:\Josh\Desktop\artefacts\artefacts\media\file_name.csv"
```

the problem is that it leaves out the last folder "csvs"
I would like it to return:

```
 "C:\Josh\Desktop\artefacts\artefacts\media\csvs\file_name.csv"
```

I would much appreciate your views
Regards

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want path_to_tzjmplist_file to contain the file's on-disk path. If that is true, I think something like this would work:

```
if request.method=='POST':
        form=UploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            files=request.FILES['file']
            evidence=request.POST['evidence']
            saved_object = form.save()
            path_to_tzjmplist_file = saved_object.file.name
```

Comment: is there something i should import? i get an error 'Uploaded_csvs' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 0):

You should save the form first (so that the object is created) before accessing its properties, and then from the *instance* you can get the path with [`name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name):

```
if request.method=='POST':
        form=UploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()  # Saves to the database
            files=request.FILES['file']
            evidence=request.POST['evidence']
            #path_to_tzjmplist_file=default_storage.path(files)
            file_name_with_path = obj.name
```

Comment: i get an error 'Uploaded_csvs' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Is there anything i should import?